# bpm for tempo of minim (half note) and 96bpm in cut time

Tags: time-signatures, tempo

If I have a minim (half note) and a tempo of 96 in cut time (2/2), what does it mean? I'm doing  it in 96 tempo but don't know if that's correct, or should I do it in 192bpm?

Comment: At 96 BPM, each beat is 5/8 of a second, a dotted minim is 1 and 1/2 beats in cut time, so it’s 5/8 seconds plus 5/16 seconds which is 15/16 seconds so each dotted minim (half note) is just under one second long. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: Hi im confused even more now. im asking how many bpm I should put the metronome on

Comment: Why wouldn’t you put the metronome at 96 BPM? Whatever tempo you want to play at is what you set the metronome to. Are you using some kind of software or beatmaking tool or are you just playing an instrument?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I was just wondering what the purpose of  (dotted minim=96) was written down on the sheet music if it altered the bpm. im playing sax and clarinet not at the same time ofcourse lol

Comment: What are you seeing that looks like the dotted minim is altering the BPM? Can you post a picture of that part of the music? Oh you’re seeing **dotted minim=96** at the top? If so then the music is probably not cut time. It’s some other time signature. If you can post a photo of the top of the first page I think we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In your comments you have clarified that it is a minim not a dotted minim*

## What does a minim = 96 bpm mean?

[image]

This means minims would be played at 96 beats per minute. For a simple metronome with *bpm* relative to a crotchet you would simply need to double the bpm because a crotchet is half a minim.

Therefore, **yes your tempo in respects to crotchets would be 192bpm.** However, musicians do not play this speed on the metronome and instead **play 96bpm but every "beat" plays the length of a minim.**

Thus, the following bars have the first 2 bars equal the last 2 bars (in terms of duration):

[image]